# Force HTTPS on all pages in the frontend, not just Checkout/Account

Tags: frontend, ssl, https, base-url

In the backend, I've enabled **Use Secure URLs in the Frontend**. But users can still visit my site through non-secure URLs, except for checkout/account pages.

I want to force secure URLs on all pages. What I do right now is change the unsecure base URL to "https://...."

It seems working. If users use HTTP, they'll be redirected to https. But I wonder if this is the correct way to do it. Any side effects?

Comment: ive heard that correct way is to override secure route in config.xml

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default answer is, set the unsecure base url to https://
depending on your setup this already is enough for a redirect if users try to use http://

Maybe a redirect on webserver level is better, as it avoids requests going through php first.

And if you want the real perfectly secure solution, you should add your website on https://hstspreload.appspot.com/ .
But careful with this, if you need to change your certificate, this can cause big problems. Let your Hoster care about this Part.

Comment: Why change the certificate? HSTS "only" makes, that the browser accesses the page from now on only via HTTPS. I made a module for this: https://github.com/ikonoshirt/StrictTransportSecurity

Comment: Maybe I mixed this up a bit with certificate pinning. Thought the preloading would also contain fingerprint for the certificate

Comment: @Flyingmana: If you look at the [actual HSTS preload list in the Chromium source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json), the vast majority of entries don't contain a certificate fingerprint or anything of the sort, just the domain name.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone stumbling across this (like I did)

Don't use htaccess. Under admin go `Stores -> General -> Web and change -> Use Secure URLs on Storefront -> Yes and Use Secure URLs in Admin -> Yes`

There's no need to edit any files.

Comment: Whoa, good timing. answered yesterday. I believe this should be the answer... at least, it is forcing https on frontend and admin for me without touching apache. The currently selected answer enables HTTPS, but this answer "forces" https.

Comment: This is exactly what the questioner said their tried and that it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

you can do this with .htaccess in apache.  Use these lines:

```
############################ Force SSL ############################
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
############################ Force SSL ############################
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the previous solutions and even though they seemed to work they locked me out of admin panel (don't completely understand the reason).

To get into the admin panel again I had to get into phpmyadmin and get into to database table **core_config_data** and change both **paths**: **web/secure/use_in_adminhtml** and **web/unsecure/base_url** get back into the admin panel again. And don't forget to clear out the cache folder if you have to make edits in the database...

So I applied the following .htaccess solution instead which let me login to admin as well

```
# AFTER THIS SECTION
############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# PUT THIS 
############# ALL PAGES HTTPS #################
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/downloader/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
############# ALL PAGES HTTPS #################
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1):

Most approaches on .htaccess would redirect most pages to home when accessed via http.

Example:
http://www.mystore.com/productA.html => http://www.mystore.com/

instead of https://www.mystore.com/productA.html

I solved it with the following .htaccess rewrite (Apache only, of course):

```
#Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

See [source](https://www.createhosting.co.nz/support/knowledgebase/85/How-to-redirect-all-http----requests-to-https----in-Magento.html).