# .htaccess redirect to ssl and non-www

Tags: redirect, .htaccess

I need a redirect handeling url's like this:

**http ==> https**
**www ==> non-www**

Somebody calling http://www.mydomain.de/mypath ==> https://mydomain.de/mypath

At the moment he gets redirected to https://mydomain.de

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes but the other one is not answered correctly, so I'm asking again. Also the http => https is not in the question.

Comment: https redirection is just another duplicate: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/70405/22855

Comment: I already force that by configuration as linked by mam08ixo. But the behaviour is that `http://domain.com/somepath` is always redirected to `https://domain.com`